# Dynamic Programming to find all palindromic substrings

Tags: algorithm, matrix, dynamic-programming

I was trying to solve a question via dynamic programming. I have a string and I need to find all the possible palindromic substrings. Say, I have a string of length `n`. I have created a matrix `n*n` for the lookup. A cell `(i,j)` is either 1 or 0. If it is 1, it means that the substring[i..j] is a palindrome, otherwise 0. Initially the diagonals are 1 because every character itself is a palindrome.

I need to fill the matrix properly as stated above.

I figured out the following:

1. If substring[i..j] is a plaindrome, then I can find if substring[i-1..j+1] is palindrome in `O(1)` time by checking if matrix[i][j]==1 and word[i-1] == word[j+1]..

How can I go about filling the matrix, for other general cases.

**A small explanation with pseudocode/language specific implementation to fill out the matrix will be much appreciated**

[image: Initial Matrix]

Edit: I need some explanation as to how and in which order the matrix gets filled (i.e diagonally, horizontally etc) . I want to solve the question by filling out this matrix only, and by no other method. My question is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19801081/find-all-substrings-that-are-palindromes)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19801081/find-all-substrings-that-are-palindromes

Comment: If you define substring as substring(start, end) instead of substring(start, length) then half of your matrix will be zero since it's invalid values (end < start)

Comment: @samgak: I know that!!! The diagonally upper right half of the matrix is going to be 0 always

Comment: You need to check all the length 2 substrings too, and from there you can use your rule to produce the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The palindromic substrings can be checked from whose length is one to N.

```
  For i from 1 to n
       Mark all substring of length i is palindromic or not.
```

pseudocode: (string array 1-based)

```
for len=1 to n:  // check string from length 1 to n
    for i=1 to (n-len + 1):  // substring start from 1 to （n-len+1)
        j = i + len - 1
        if len == 1:
           matrix[i][j]==1 
        else if len == 2:
           if array[i] == array[j]:
               matrix[i][j] = 1
           else:
               matrix[i][j] = 0
        else:
           if matrix[i+1][j-1] == 1 and array[i] == array[j]:
               matrix[i][j] = 1
           else:
               matrix[i][j] = 0
```

Comment: Can you explain the line "Mark length i strings as palindromic or not" ??

Comment: @User_Targaryen I'm sorry. It must be, mark the substring of length i is palindromic or not. I will edit it.