# How to write a Javascript function to get all palindromic subsequences from string in order?

Tags: javascript, string, palindrome, subsequence

A subsequence is a group of characters chosen from a list while maintaining their order. For instance, the subsequenes of the string `abc` are `[a, b, c, ab, ac, bc, abc]`.

Now, I need to write a function to return all the palindromic subsequences from a given string **in order**. For instance, for the string `acdapmpomp`, the output should be `[a,c,d,p,m,o,aa,aca,ada,pmp,mm,mom,pp,ppp,pop,mpm,pmpmp]`.

My code is:

```js
function getAllPalindromicSubsequences(str) {
    var result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        for (let j = i + 1; j < str.length + 1; j++) {
            if (str.slice(i, j).split("").reverse().join("") == str.slice(i, j)){
                result.push(str.slice(i, j));
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(getAllPalindromicSubsequences("acdapmpomp"));
```

But this produces the following output:

```
[
  'a', 'c', 'd',
  'a', 'p', 'pmp',
  'm', 'p', 'o',
  'm', 'p'
]
```

What is the mistake I am making? And what should be the correct code?

Comment: Your code clearly doesn't allow for character skips

Comment: Your code isn't collecting the subsequences correctly as you're only looking at continuous/connect groups/slices of letters from `i` to `j`

Comment: The right approach would be using dynamic programming. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39746540/dynamic-programming-to-find-all-palindromic-substrings) for instance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a recursive approach and collect all character and check is they are palindromes.

```js
function getSub(string) {
    function isPalindrome(string) {
        let l = 0,
            r = string.length - 1;

        if (!string) return false;
        while (l < r) {
            if (string[l] !== string[r]) return false;
            l++; r--;
        }
        return true;
    }
    function sub([character, ...rest], right = '') {
        if (isPalindrome(right) && !result.includes(right)) result.push(right);
        if (!character) return;
        sub(rest, right + character);
        sub(rest, right);
    }

    var result = [];
    sub([...string])
    return result;
}

console.log(getSub('acdapmpomp'));
```

Comment: Nice :) Thanks Nina!